# drupal webform styling pages

Tags: webforms

I have a form that I created using webform. I have it styled like I want on the client side but whenever I view the submissions or edit the submissions I would like to style that portion as well on the admin side but cannot find a way to style these. Can some provide some help regarding how to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [ThemeKey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey)?

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching
>   rules which allow automatic selection of a theme **depending on
>   current path**, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many
>   other properties.

Comment: I have not heard of themekey. I considered creating a view but i'm not sure if this would be the appropriate way to carry this out.

Comment: I'd give ThemeKey a try, and see where it goes. It's pretty straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with your original thought and use Views.  You're probably going to want the control over the output that you wouldn't necessarily have if you just tried to style the tables in the admin section.

Creating your own view of the submissions would give you full control vs. wrestling with the existing display.  Webform does already use Views to display the submissions table, but I don't think that it's modifiable via any UI.

Creating a view with submission #'s and edit/delete links is pretty straightforward, but if you want to display the actual submission data you'll need to use [Webform mysql Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_mysql_views).